# Is the following C++ code equiv? (in a smart pointer implementation)

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

Code 1:

```
template<class T>
const PtrInterface<T>*
PtrInterface<T>::newRef() const {
  PtrInterface<T>* me = (PtrInterface<T>*) this;
  ++me->references_;
  //++this->references_;
  return this;
}
```

Code 2:

```
template<class T>
const PtrInterface<T>*
PtrInterface<T>::newRef() const {
  //PtrInterface<T>* me = (PtrInterface<T>*) this;
  //++me->references_;
  ++this->references_;
  return this;
}
```

Is there ever *any* situation where these two blocks of code will do different things?
Thanks!

Comment: Is `references_` mutable? That's an important detail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there ever any situation where these two blocks of code will do different things?

Yes, when you are in a `const` method. Currently, the one with `me` invokes undefined behavior. Here's why:

As you know, when you call a member function, there is an implicit `this` pointer. The `this` pointer is `const` when a function is marked `const`. Take this for example:

```
struct foo
{
    void method1(void);
    void method2(void) const;

    int i;
};
```

Implicitly, the compiler generates (by the way, this is simplified):

```
void foo::method1(foo* this); 
void foo::method2(const foo* this) const;
```

So, are these two bodies the same?

```
foo* me = (foo*)this;
me->i = 1;

// and

this->i = 1;
```

The answer is *it depends*, and as stated earlier, it's dependent on the `const`-ness of the function. In a non-`const` function, they are the same:

```
void foo::method1(foo* this)
{
    foo* me = (foo*)this; // this cast is redundant
    me->i = 1;

    // ...

    this->i = 1;
}
```

But in a `const` function:

```
void foo::method2(const foo* this) const
{
    foo* me = (foo*)this; // uh-oh! acts like const_cast
    me->i = 1; // modifying a const_cast'd variable is undefined behavior

    // ...

    this->i = 1; // wouldn't compile
}
```

We end up stripping the `const` away. So, no, they aren't always the same. This is the peril of the C-style cast: it will find a way. By the way, casting `const` away in itself isn't undefined behavior; it's the modification of said variable that does it.

There is a sticky problem in your question though: your code shouldn't compile. Like in the commented code above, in your `const` method you shouldn't be able to modify `reference_`.

This is different if `reference_` is `mutable`, which I'm guessing it might be (assuming you gave us compilable code.) In this case, I'm not certain if the first sample leads to undefined behavior, since it was `mutable` in the first place. I wouldn't take the chance though.

Comment: nice edit but last answer was short and sweet :) It diff to go thru long answer without losing focus :)

Comment: @Yogesh: I felt the old one was harder to follow, this one is step-by-step "don't do it". :P

Answer (score 2):

More or less everything GMan has said, except references_ need not be mutable.  It could also be an object which has overridden operator++() to be a const member function.

Comment: True, though that's even uglier than I would imagine.